# How to determine when scroller in browser appear

Tags: javascript, scroller

I am using resize event, but when scroller appear - it change window size, but event is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the content height is higher than the inner height of the browser. Unfortunately, there is no event listener for scrollbar being added...

Answer (score 0):

You could keep tabs on the client width - it will reduce by about 20px when the scrollbar appears.